# Manually Restore GUID Partition Table on Mac

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, gpt, testdisk

Recently I plugged my HDD with one partition formatted in HFS+ into a Windows PC as an internal HDD, it somehow ruined my GUID partition table and turned it into 3 partitions (unformatted/unallocated) on MBR.

(reason for doing that, I thought that it was ExFat instead of HFS+)

I followed this guide: https://perrohunter.com/repair-a-mac-os-x-hfs-partition-table/

I have been trying to restore my partition using Testdisk, I found back the partitions with sector size = 4kb:

[image: testdisk results]

I struggled with restoring the partition with pdisk. It either shown “the map is not big enough” or some other errors.

I couldn't set up the EFI partition in any way. 
I can set the partition for the HFS+ but it still wouldn't show up.
I tried using gdisk, gpt to convert the MBR to GUID but it didn't help at all.

I'm running data recovery at the moment and it probably took forever :( So if anyone could help me to recover my old partition that'd be great!

Thank you very much!